# Using Docker and getting file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm trying to use Docker and am following the [getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) documentation but my test script shows "not found".

I'm trying to run a script: test.sh (only contains `echo "Hello"`)

My docker directory contains
`app/ docker-compose/ Dockerfile test.sh`

The Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM openjdk:8u181
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 69
ENV NAME mer
CMD "test.sh"
```

I build it like this:

```
$ docker build --tag=mer .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  303.8MB
Step 1/6 : FROM openjdk:8u181
 ---> 82942d9df443
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b2586c6519ea
Step 3/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> 8ecd700feafe
Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 69
 ---> Running in 343cb5014528
Removing intermediate container 343cb5014528
 ---> 629cdc57f74e
Step 5/6 : ENV NAME mer
 ---> Running in 53844c2ea6fd
Removing intermediate container 53844c2ea6fd
 ---> b952a8f45dc8
Step 6/6 : CMD "test.sh"
 ---> Running in 1f1ef99503b8
Removing intermediate container 1f1ef99503b8
 ---> ffe838007e82
Successfully built ffe838007e82
Successfully tagged mer:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

and run it like so:

```
$ docker run mer:latest
/bin/sh: 1: test.sh: not found
```

Why does it say "test.sh: not found"?

My environment: Windows 10 with Docker Desktop 2.1 running commands through Cygwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `test.sh` from the `/app` directory which is where it was `COPY`'d after you set it as the `WORKDIR`:

```
CMD "/app/test.sh"
```

I encourage you to consider using [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) rather than [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

Because you're using a Bash process, you will likely wish to continue to use the [shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example), i.e.

```
ENTRYPOINT "/app/test.sh"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I wish the documentation explained it more clearly

Comment: You're welcome. The documentation is good but -- as always -- could be improved ;-) Hopefully either those links or a Google on the subject will help explain `ENTRYPOINT` vs `CMD` too. It's a nuance but I think it's good practice.